# How to show weather icons when using open weather API?

Tags: android, web-services, weather-api, openweathermap

I use open-weather API to display weather situation at my android app and there is no problem, but I want to display weather icons too, can anyone tell me what's wrong with my code? OR what else I should do?

```
iconCode= weatherResponse.getCode();
String iconUrl = "http://openweathermap.org/img/w/" + iconCode + ".png";
Picasso.with(getApplicationContext()).load(iconUrl).into(weatherImage);
```

Comment: Could you include the appropriate files (such as the code used to define the `weatherImage` variable, the layout XML file for that particular activity/fragment) in your question?

Comment: try printing out your `iconUrl` and see if it actually takes you to an image

Comment: Thank you, you are right, I checked iconURL and it was empty, I fixed it.